# Bitbake not finding files specified in SRC_URI when changing directory name

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

I'm writing a recipe that copies some configuration files over to my image (like a cramfs.conf that goes into /etc/modprobe.d to disable cramfs). Here is the structure of my recipe directory:

```
.
├── compliance-config.bb
└── configs
    └── fs
        ├── 1-1-1-1-cramfs.conf
        ├── 1-1-1-2-freevxfs.conf
        ...
```

In my recipe I do the following:

```
SRC_URI += "file://fs"                                                              
                                                                                    
do_install() {                                                                      
    install -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/modprobe.d/                                        
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/fs/*.conf ${D}${sysconfdir}/modprobe.d/              
}
```

This works, but when I change the folder name of `fs` to something more descriptive (and of course accordingly change the `SRC_URI` and path in `do_install()`), it doesn't find the files anymore and gives me (Edit: to clarify, this error happens when I change the directory name from `fs` to `fsconfigs` for example, tried different names to make sure I don't accidentally name it in a forbidden way, names like `abctest` also don't work).

```
ERROR: compliance-config-1.0-r0 do_fetch: Fetcher failure: Unable to find file file://fsconfigs anywhere. The paths that were searched were:
[...long list of paths...]
```

So I thought I needed to do a clean build, but running `bitbake -c clean <image>` or `bitbake -fc cleanall <image>` beforehand doesn't help.

Why does bitbake not find my files if I change the specified directory?

Answer (score 0):

This is a better :

```
.
├── compliance-config.bb
└── files
      ├── 1-1-1-1-cramfs.conf
      ├── 1-1-1-2-freevxfs.conf
```

Then add `SRC_URI += "file://fsconfigs"` for instance.

You should know that the default `FILESPATH` variable is the default set of directories the OpenEmbedded build system uses when searching for patches and files.

The default value for the `FILESPATH` variable is defined in the base.bbclass as follow :

```
FILESPATH = "${@base_set_filespath(["${FILE_DIRNAME}/${BP}", \
"${FILE_DIRNAME}/${BPN}", "${FILE_DIRNAME}/files"], d)}"
```

Here `${BP}` stand for the base recipe name and your Package Version: `${BPN}-${PV}`

If you want the build system to look in directories other than the defaults, the best practiec is to extend the FILESPATH variable **by using the FILESEXTRAPATHS variable**.

Note that SRC_URI is used to specify files, not directories.

https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html?highlight=filesextrapaths

Comment: The files are in the directory, the example I provided above works, but it doesn't work anymore when I change the directory name, for example from `fs` to `fsconfigs`. I wonder why that is, since even with a clean build it doesn't change.